# How do I renew a Facebook user_access_token if I deal with a lot of AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Please tell me if I'm understanding correctly. (because I might not be.)

1. User posts something on my site. (He checked "also post to Facebook".)
2. Client sends an AJAX POST request to my server, and my server inserts the record in my database.
3. The server realizes the the facebook user access token is expired, so it sends the response back to the client, while storing the post in a session.
4. The client does a `window.location.replace(facebook_oauth_dialog_url)`
5. Then the user will see a sudden "flash", going to Facebook, then coming back to the website. My server picks up the new access token.
6. My server checks the session to see what should be posted to Facebook. And then, it uses the new access token to post that to Facebook.

Is it really this tedious? Why can't I renew the app server-side without the user going through the dialog?

My entire site is Backbone.js. That means, it's one big page. I can't jump the user back and forth between Facebook and my website like this.

Comment: Now that's a bounty :)!

Comment: for offline_access? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/

Comment: When you renew an access token if user is logged in facebook he doesn't see any dialog. What is exactly your question?

Comment: Which SDK you are using(e.g.PHP-SDK,C#SDK)?

Comment: check up my answer its updated :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea is to make use of the [Facebook JS-SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) methods:

1. User check the *Post To Facebook* option
2. you check if the current user is connected to your app (using `FB.getLoginStatus()`)
3. if the user is connected, you have two options:

   - post directly using the `FB.api` method or
   - Send the `access_token` to your server to complete the post process there
4. if the user is not connected (or not logged in to Facebook), use the `FB.login()` method

Here's a quick example (with a **Live [Demo](http://www.masteringapi.com/labs/fb/test.html)**!) for you to get started:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
var fbLoaded = false;
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      //channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    fbLoaded = true;
    // Additional initialization code here

};

function postForm() {
    var msg = document.myForm.msg.value;
    // do form validation here, e.g:
    if(!msg.length) {
        alert("You should enter a message!");
        return false;
    }

    // do we need to post to Facebook?
    if(document.myForm.toFB.checked) {
        // is the library loaded?
        if(!fbLoaded) {
            alert("Facebook JS-SDK is not yet loaded. Please try again later or uncheck Post To Facebook option");
            return false;
        }

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                /* 
                *  message can be posted to Facebook directly
                *  using the FB.api method or accessToken
                *  can be sent to the server and do the call
                *  from there
                */
                myAjaxCall(msg, accessToken);
            } else {
                // status is either not_authorized or unknown
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                        myAjaxCall(msg, accessToken);
                    } else {
                        alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                    }
                }, {scope: 'publish_stream'});
            }
        });
    } else {
        myAjaxCall(msg);
    }
    return false;
}

function myAjaxCall(m,a) {
    alert("Here you make the ajax call\nMessage: " + m + "\nAccess Token: " + a);
}

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>

<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="post" onSubmit="return postForm()">
<p><label>Your Message:</label><br/><textarea name="msg"></textarea></p>
<p><label>Post to Facebook?</label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="toFB" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect answer. How do I give you extra bounty?

Comment: Thanks! well, I'm not sure...I guess you should wait for a couple of days before you'll be able to set another bounty on the question. Maybe it's a good question in the [Meta website](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @Pooya's update is totally valid! once the user granted your app the `publish_stream` permission. No need for an `access_token` (the user ID is enough. Check my answer [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4814432/publishing-to-users-wall-without-being-online-logged-in-facebook-sharing-usin/4816134#4816134). But still, since the user is online when publishing, using `/me/feed` + user `access_token` in the backend is still a valid approach!

Answer (score 2):

Before posting to the server, call `FB.getLoginStatus()` on the client to get the latest access token. There is no flash when using this method and no user interaction, as it simply grabs a new access token.

```js
FB.getLoginStatus( function ( response ) {
    if ( response.authResponse ) { 
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        //post to server
    };
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope you known that if you have publish_stream permission you don't need access token here is documentation for [publish_stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) and  **Below is the solution for four scenarios**

1.The token expires after expires time (2 hours is the default).
2.The user changes his/her password which invalidates the access token.
3.The user de-authorizes your app.
4.The user logs out of Facebook.

To ensure the best experience for your users, your app needs to be prepared to catch errors for the above scenarios. The following PHP code shows you how to handle these errors and retrieve a new access token.

When you redirect the user to the auth dialog, the user is not prompted for permissions if the user has already authorized your application. Facebook will return you a valid access token without any user facing dialog. However if the user has de-authorized your application then the user will need to re-authorize your application for you to get the access_token.

```
<?php
$app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
$app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET"; 
$my_url = "YOUR_POST_LOGIN_URL";

// known valid access token stored in a database 
$access_token = "YOUR_STORED_ACCESS_TOKEN";

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

// If we get a code, it means that we have re-authed the user 
//and can get a valid access_token. 
if (isset($code)) {
$token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
  . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) 
  . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret 
  . "&code=" . $code . "&display=popup";
$response = file_get_contents($token_url);
$params = null;
parse_str($response, $params);
$access_token = $params['access_token'];
}


// Attempt to query the graph:
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?"
. "access_token=" . $access_token;
$response = curl_get_file_contents($graph_url);
$decoded_response = json_decode($response);

//Check for errors 
if ($decoded_response->error) {
// check to see if this is an oAuth error:
if ($decoded_response->error->type== "OAuthException") {
  // Retrieving a valid access token. 
  $dialog_url= "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
    . "client_id=" . $app_id 
    . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url);
  echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url 
  . "'</script>");
}
else {
  echo "other error has happened";
}
} 
else {
// success
echo("success" . $decoded_response->name);
echo($access_token);
}

// note this wrapper function exists in order to circumvent PHP’s 
//strict obeying of HTTP error codes.  In this case, Facebook 
//returns error code 400 which PHP obeys and wipes out 
//the response.
function curl_get_file_contents($URL) {
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
$contents = curl_exec($c);
$err  = curl_getinfo($c,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($c);
if ($contents) return $contents;
else return FALSE;
}
?>
```

for more details info you can visit this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/)
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

well you are doing something wrong you do not need to renew access token even if its expired all you need is sending user facebook id & content you want to post together to your server by ajax then post it without access token Just check up here

## [Publish Stream from the application - for non logged in user, using Graph API, php SDK](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9345391/publish-stream-from-the-application-for-non-logged-in-user-using-graph-api-p/9347932#comment11949255_9347932)

if you have publish_stream permission you dont need access token 
this is documentation for publish_stream 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

> Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's
>   stream and to the streams of the user's friends. With this permission,
>   you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, without
>   requiring offline_access. However, please note that Facebook
>   recommends a user-initiated sharing model.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the problem in another project.

The way I handle it is to create a hidden iframe. The first time you need the user to accept the privilege, use your main window to redirect. then, when you are sure that the user has already accepted the privilege, use the hidden iframe to communicate with facebook.

The user will not see the "flash" because it will done in an iframe.

I've done it with GWT. Here is the code I used : it communicates with Facebook via the iframe and do a check on access token every 500ms to see if the token is valid.

The code is in java (compiled in javascript using gwt).

```
public class FacebookConnector extends Composite
{
        public static final String                                      ARG_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES        = "fb_accessTokenExpires";
        public static final String                                      ARG_GAME_FACEBOOK_NAME          = "gameFBName";
        public static final String                                      ARG_GAME_FACEBOOK_ID            = "gameFBId";

        private static FacebookConnectorUiBinder        uiBinder                                        = GWT.create(FacebookConnectorUiBinder.class);

        interface FacebookConnectorUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, FacebookConnector>
        {
        }

        private static FacebookConnector        me;

        public static FacebookConnector getInstance()
        {
                if (me == null)
                {
                        me = new FacebookConnector();
                }

                return me;
        }

        @UiField
        IFrameElement   iframe;

        private Date    accessToken;
        private Timer   timer;

        protected FacebookConnector()
        {
                initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

                if (ArgManager.getArg(ARG_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES) != null)
                {
                        accessToken = new Date(Long.parseLong(ArgManager.getArg(ARG_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES)));
                }
        }

        public void checkAccessToken(final AbstractAsyncCallback<Void> callback)
        {
                if (accessToken == null || accessToken.before(new Date()))
                {
                        // send authentication
                        String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id="
                                        + ArgManager.getArg(ARG_GAME_FACEBOOK_ID) + "&scope=user_birthday,email&redirect_uri="
                                        + ArgManager.getArg(ArgManager.ARG_URL_FACEBOOK_BASE) + "page/facebook-step2%3FgameName%3D"
                                        + ArgManager.getGameShortcut();

                        iframe.setSrc(url);

                        // check url
                        timer = new Timer() {

                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                        ClientFactory.getInstance().getService().getAccessTokenExpires(new AbstractAsyncCallback<Date>() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(Date result)
                                                {
                                                        super.onSuccess(result);

                                                        if (result != null && result.after(new Date()))
                                                        {
                                                                accessToken = result;

                                                                // call the callback
                                                                callback.onSuccess(null);
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                                // try again in one second
                                                                timer.schedule(1000);
                                                        }

                                                }

                                        });

                                }
                        };

                        // launch timer in 500 milliseconds
                        timer.schedule(500);
                }
                else
                {
                        callback.onSuccess(null);
                }
        }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply do a server side exchange because that bypasses the user's control of the authorization.

Like others have said, you should use the javascript sdk to facilitate updating the access token.  By default, it uses an iframe and falls back on a popup to handle communicating with Facebook.  This should work well with your backbone.js application.

I like to define a javascript function that takes success and denied callbacks to execute after checking the facebook auth status:

```
function checkFBAuth(success, denied, scope) {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            success(response);
        } else {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    success(response);
                } else {
                    denied(response);
                }
            }, scope);
        } 
    });
};
```

This will go ahead and run `FB.login` if the user's session has expired.  In your success callback, you could also pass `response.authResponse.signedRequest` as signed_request in your AJAX POST data.  This will allow most FB SDK's (for example, the PHP SDK) to recognize and validate the signed request and set the user id and access token.  You could also pass the whole `response.authResponse` data with your POST.  That has the accessToken, userID, and expiresIn time.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/ for the docs on the Facebook Developers site.

Also, if you enable the offline access deprecation migration, you can exchange access token to extend the expiration date to 60 days instead of the default 2 hours.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/

Answer (score 0):

Like @ThinkingStiff said, the key point is that you need to *call FB.getLoginStatus() on the client to get the latest access token*

These days, all the cool kids are handling their logins and retrieving their access tokens via JavaScript with the SDK. And hey, why not? The users love it!

After the JavaScript SDK retrieves the access token, all AJAX requests to your server will have access to that access token as well. That is, it is automatically passed along with each 
AJAX request in the form of a cookie.

So, on the server side, you can retrieve the access token via cookies (our friend StackOverflow has some Answers related to finding that cookie). However, if you do the other cool thing and use the PHP SDK you won't even have to give it a second thought, because it will automatically grab the cookie for you, if it's there!

Comment: Javascript SDK is the way to go for this, it's a far better user experience. The backend route is tedious.